# Multiple Ad companies in one App (Google Play) AdMob and Amazon/Millennial Ads?

Tags: google-app-engine, admob, millennial-media

I have a simple question but am unable to find the answer anywhere. I have an App and would like to put ads on it. Can I use two ad companies like Millenial Ads and AdMob to display ads in my app? are there any restrictions to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add more than one ad provider for a single app. There're two ways to do that.

1. Show different ads at different place.

   You can try interstitial ads, which are basically full screen or you can also use banners of from different networks at different screens of your App.
2. Use network mediation.

   It is considered better and is relatively easy and less risky. You choose one main network provider and mediate other network provider's ads through the SDK of main ad provider. The priority of the ad provider can be manually set in dashboard, although not all providers give that option.